# Laravel Secondary database connection does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one MySQL database connection in `config/database.php` as below, and it is working fine.

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

I am trying to define another alternate connection (for testing purposes) as below. (Same host but different database):

```php
'mysql_testing' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TEST', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_TEST', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_TEST', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

where `DB_DATABASE_TEST`, `DB_USERNAME_TEST` and `DB_PASSWORD_TEST` are defined in `.env` as below:

```php
DB_DATABASE_TEST=db_other
DB_USERNAME_TEST=usr_other
DB_PASSWORD_TEST=secret
```

However, this second connection does *not* work. In Tinker, if I try to use the new connection:

> DB::connection('mysql_testing')->getPdo()
>   InvalidArgumentException with message 'Database [mysql_testing] not 
>       configured.'

If I try to check the config values, `mysql` works but the new connection `mysql_testing` returns null.

```php
Config::get('database.connections.mysql')
[
 "driver" => "mysql",
 "host" => "127.0.0.1",
 "port" => "3306",
 "database" => "***",
 "username" => "***",
 "password" => "***",
 "charset" => "utf8",
 "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci",
 "prefix" => "",
 "strict" => false,
 "engine" => null,
]

Config::get('database.connections.mysql_testing')
null
```

Any idea how may I debug this issue?

Comment: Hey hashbrown , have you ever got solution of it? I am facing same issue and I even tried putting: `Artisan::call('cache:clear', ['-n'=>true]);
            Artisan::call('config:clear', ['-n'=>true]);` after switching to another database but no luck

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because Laravel 5 automatically caches the config values. Therefore, even if we change the config/database.php values, the changes wouldn't take effect as Laravel will continue to read it from cache.

There's a way to clear the cache. **But this will not clear config cache**

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Luckily, there is a different artisan command for that. 
To clear the config cache you need to use

```
php artisan config:clear
```